# bash: jump to bottom of terminal

Tags: bash

I want to do the same thing that the "top" command does on exit:

Print something on the screen, then jump to the bottom of the terminal window so that the prompt is located on the bottom line.

(If I just print 1000 empty lines I will lose what I have printed on the screen, so I need a more elegant solution to get to the bottom of the terminal window)

How to achieve this in bash?

Comment: Top doesn't really do this: It reprints the entire screen every few seconds, so the terminal has been scrolled a bunch and the cursor has hit the bottom by the time you exit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tput cup $(tput lines) 0
```

In general, `tput cup X Y` moves the cursor to position X, Y (counting from the upper left corner.)  `tput lines` or `tput li` gives you the max X value on the current terminal.  Note that `tput li` relies on a terminfo capability that may not be present, but `tput cup 1000 0` should have the same effect (assuming your tty has less than 1000 lines!)  If you want to print something on the screen starting at a particular location, there's really no need to "jump to the bottom", you can do things like: `clear; tput cup 5 0; printf hello; sleep 1; tput cup 5 0; printf world; tput el; tput cup $(tput li) 0`

Comment: It tells me `tput: unknown terminfo capability 'li'` and jumps to the top instead of the bottom, but it looks promising ;-)

Comment: @Will: [ Off-topic comment ]: I was trying to see that behavior from `strace` call on `top` was seeing bytes written using `print` on standard output as `write(1, "\33[?1l\33>\33[49;1H\n\33[?12l\33[?25h\33[K", 30
) = 30`. Does those bytes anyway relate to the screen positions? (could not be relevant totally)

Comment: @RolandSeuhs Yes, the terminfo capability is an annoyance.  You can try `tput cup $LINES 0` or use a big number: `tput cup 1000 0`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thanks, tput cup 1000 0 is exactly right, please change answer so I can give you the award

Comment: @Inian `tput` uses the escape sequences particular to the tty on which it is  run, and those bytes are relevant.  You could use `printf` to write those bytes to get the same effect, but `tput` is a much cleaner way to do it.

Comment: it's not  $(tput li), but ` $(tput lines)`, it's works on my debian (not li)

Comment: @kyodev Interesting.  It looks like the capability name is "lines", and the code is "li". Both `tput li` and `tput lines` works on macos, but only `tput lines` works on Debian.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: yes, on [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_mono/tput.html#SEC7), only Name is used, no termcap, I assume

Comment: a good [practice to call tput](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037)

Answer (score 0):

In bash you have the LINES and COLUMNS variables containing the size of terminal, these variables are updated when you resize the terminal window.

I suggest to use, for your request the following example:

```
echo -ne "\E[${LINES};0H"
```

It works on terminal using ansi commands.